# Iterating over, and mutating a multi-dimensional array of objects, of undetermined depth, with JS/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects, that looks something like that:

```
treeData: [
    { title: 'Some site',
     url: 'www.somesite.com',
     children: [{ title: 'Another site', url: 'www.anothersite.com' }] },
     { title: 'Good site',
     url: 'www.goodsite.com',
     children: [{ title: 'Bad site', url: 'www.badsite.com',children:[same 
     pattern...] }] }
    ]
```

Each object has "title" and "url" properties, and it might also have a "children" array, which follows the same pattern. I need to iterate through each object, add a "subtitle" property, which is identical to the "url" one. If it were only two-dimensional, i could just check if it has "children" property and act accordingly, but being that it can have any number of dimensions(imagine a multi-dimensional navbar dropdown menu), i thought about going for the recursive function solution. I did something like that:

```
static convertUrlsToSubTitles(treeData) {

_.each(treeData, function (menu) {

  menu.subtitle = menu.url
  console.log(menu.subtitle)
  if (menu.children && menu.children.length > 0) {
    menu.children.forEach((child) => {
      SortableMenu.convertUrlsToSubTitles(menu.children);
    })        

  }
});

return treeData;

}
```

This is of course totally flawed, and works only for the first dimension. How can this be done? Any type of solution will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your code should work just fine, even with deeper levels of nesting. You don't need to check for length of the children, just if it has children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. It's as simple as this:

```
static convertUrlsToSubTitles(collection) {
    for (let item of collection) {
        item.subtitle = item.url;
        if (item.children) {
            SortableMenu.convertUrlsToSubTitles(item.children);
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that I omitted the `return` statement since technically it's not
  required - the function modifies the same "tree" object you pass into
  it as you call it because objects (such as arrays) are passed by
  reference and not copied and thus no need to return the same
  reference.
- I used a `for...of` loop instead of Lodash's `_.each` or standard `forEach` since this avoids the need to create many function objects when traversing very deep "trees".